# What is the difference between the words "address" and "adress"?

Tags: forms-of-address

I and another person had a dispute. I said that the word "adress" in the English language does not exist, but I was told that I was wrong and I should correctly write "adress", and not "address". Does the word "adress" exist at all?

I found this comparison:
https://wikidiff.com/adress/address

Comment: Welcome to ELL.SE. You have not told us what exactly you intend *adress* or *address* to mean, but checking any major dictionary would tell you that *adress* is not a standard English word. Questions which can be answered by checking a common reference are not on-topic here.

Comment: @choster, I speak English a little bit.

I wanted an answer from a native English speaker. My College teacher didn't believe me (she is not native English speaker). I received an answer to the question and sent a link to the answer to the teacher.

Comment: A dictionary should be a far better authority to your teacher than some website populated by anonymous people of unknown credentials.

Answer (score 6):

The instruction you link to is complete rubbish. Ignore it.

The noun designating a location and the verb meaning *speak to* are *address*, with two ds.

*Adress* is not an English word; if you want to speak of an item of clothing you may speak of *a dress*, two words.

Comment: I am very happy to see this as an outright, true assertion.

Answer (score 4):

Wikidiff says, on the page that you linked to:

> adress
>
> Not English
>
> Adress has no English definition.
>   **It may be misspelled.**

That is exactly right. "Adress" with one 'd' is not a recognised English word. It is, however, the correct spelling of the Swedish word meaning 'street address'.